# Insert a new column if value of previous column has some matching string

Tags: linux, bash

I want to perform a simple bash script. The requirement is as follows:

- The data has the delimiter of csv (,)
- The columns are inconsistent
- I want to insert a column 'NA' if previous column data is 'login_success'

The data is as follows:

> 2022.01.26,00:37:08,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,abc
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_failed,User_not_authenticated,BASIC_LOGIN,
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,xyz
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:10,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,abc123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,xyz123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,abc
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,xyz
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:12,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,pqr
> 2022.01.26,00:37:13,login_failed,Token_does_not_exist,TOKEN_LOGIN,
> 2022.01.26,00:37:13,login_success,BASIC_LOGIN,abc123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:14,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,xyz123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:14,login_success,TOKEN_LOGIN,pqr123

Desired output:

> 2022.01.26,00:37:08,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,abc
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_failed,User_not_authenticated,BASIC_LOGIN,
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,xyz
> 2022.01.26,00:37:09,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:10,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,abc123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,xyz123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,abc
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,xyz
> 2022.01.26,00:37:11,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:12,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,pqr
> 2022.01.26,00:37:13,login_failed,Token_does_not_exist,TOKEN_LOGIN,
> 2022.01.26,00:37:13,login_success,NA,BASIC_LOGIN,abc123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:14,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,xyz123
> 2022.01.26,00:37:14,login_success,NA,TOKEN_LOGIN,pqr123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
sed 's/\(,login_success\),/\1,NA,/g' file.csv
```

Comment: Yep, `sed` is the proper tool for the job. `awk` is just a bit messier here inserting the additional field. Would be worth mentioning the `-i` option to edit-in-place, but that can be looked up easily enough.

Comment: Perferct! Thanks guys. That solved my problem. And here I thought I would need a script to do that! Kudos!